# Oh no, not another Undefined Reference question!

Tags: c, gcc, linker, compilation, undefined-reference

Unfortunately yes.

I have my shared library compiled, the linker doesn't complain about not finding it but still I get undefined reference error. Thinking that I might be doing something wrong I did a little research and found this nice, simple walkthrough:

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

which I've followed to the letter but still I get:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L.\ -lmean
/tmp/ccZjkkkl.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `mean'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is pretty simple stuff so what's going wrong?! Is there something in my set up that might need checking/tweeking?

GCC 4.3.2 Fedora 10 64-bit

Comment: '\' is not the path separator.  '/' is.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L.\ -lmean
```

to:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L. -lmean
```

---

*You probably meant to do this:*

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L./ -lmean
```

*which is OK, but the trailing `/` is redundant*

Comment: Agreed but...

$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L./ -lmean
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmean
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

and...

$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L. -lmean
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmean
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

So now ld can't seem to find the library whereas with

$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked  -L.\ -lmean
/tmp/cceWR2jQ.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `mean'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Seems to be saying 'library found' but refuse to link :(

Weird.

Comment: @roony: no - the \ character you used originally escapes the next character (space in this case) so you were actually just passing `". -lmean"` as the path to `-L`. You are now passing a library with the corrected command line, but it's not being found. It should be named `libmean.so` or similar.

Comment: Yup! The library is libmean.so yet [[$ gcc -Wall main.c -o dynamically_linked -L -lmean]] still yields undefined ref to `mean' in main arghh!

Comment: @roony: is that a typo or do you really not have a `.` after the `-L` ?

Comment: err.. I did but that's gone now. My current attempt is exactly as shown in my previous comment. It's utterly bizarre. I'm scanning through old makefiles for clues but nothing I try works!

Comment: @roony: am I right in thinking that libmean.so is in the current directory ? If so then you need `-L.` to tell the linker where to find it (`.` means the current directory). If not then you need to put the appropriate path after `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

How was the library created? Libtool?

Show us an ls -l of your current directory, and look at what `gcc -v <rest of your command>` says (that gives details of what gcc is doing).